# macOS installation failed; stuck in reboot loop

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, catalina, install

MacBook Pro Retina 15-inch mid-2012

I was running High Sierra and upgraded to Catalina. I checked if it was compatible with my Mac before doing so and the Apple site said it was.

I installed it, and about 75% through, it says it had to restart due to a problem, and then it keeps restarting in a loop over and over.

Tried the following:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>: reinstalled Catalina but the same thing happens.

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>: same as above

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>: gives me the option to reinstall OS X but there is no drive showing up to install it on.

What can I do? I have Mojave installed on an external hard drive. Can I install this using the HDD? I’d like to keep my data intact if possible.

Comment: So you can boot the Mac from this external install of Mojave?  Good.  Back up your files IMMEDIATELY.

Comment: I do not know if I can boot using this Mojave installer on the HDD. I'm not from a tech background so I have no idea. I just remembered I had downloaded Mojave and left it on a backup on the HDD. I do have access to another Macbook so I can follow instructions online and make a bootable installer if that will work?

Comment: "I’d like to keep my data intact if possible." You should ALWAYS have a backup copy of your files, if you want to keep them. If the Mac boots from the external, then you know the problem is something on the internal drive. It's an SSD, so it's probably fine, but you may need to reformat it, and doing so will lose your data.

Comment: @benwiggy Thanks. I'm not able to use the external HDD to start up. The volume doesn't even show up when trying Option/Alt upon booting. Any ideas how to work around that? I do have a backup but it's not a very recent one unfortunately. My mistake.

Comment: It could be that the newer OSes (Mojave and Catalina) require a firmware update, which your Mac doesn't have. I know it's an old Mac, but I'd see if an Apple Store (or another Apple certified repair shop) might take a look at it.

Comment: @benwiggy After reading your comment I tried High Sierra on a USB and HDD but those don't show up either. Oddly enough, I plugged in my other HDD with the old backups of my data and that showed up, with the title "Recovery 10.9" I haven't done anything with that since I don't want to mess around further (I'm not tech background). Do you have any further suggestions for me? Thanks

Comment: OK, if one external drive works, that proves that the hardware is ok. The question is: why are all the other drives not working?

Comment: @benwiggy I found out why. Because apple care did not talk me through turning it into a bootable disk while using terminal on another mac! They said to only download the OS and plug it in. Once I made it a bootable drive, it showed up, but I couldn't downgrade to Mojave since Catalina is newer. I tried to download a new copy of Catalina but App Store only gives me a stub and internet recovery download leads to the same kernel panic. Good news though is that a friend helped me retrieve a backup via Terminal. Thank you so much for your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

If you were to ask someone else to fix this for you, in all likelihood they would have one or more of the following three items:

1. An installer on an external drive or USB.
2. A second "good" mac to fix yours with.
3. A clean OS install on an external drive or USB.

#1 - The installer should boot simply by plugging it into the drive - which then lets you move the existing install out the way and do a fresh install - assuming there are no hardware issues with this mac that should get you up and running again.

#2 - Macs can be put into Target mode which basically just turns them into an external drive that can be mounted onto another Mac. This allow someone to copy all the files off wipe the drive and then start the re-install process.

#3 - A clean OS image works in a similar way to the previous option, except you don't need a second mac - you boot of the external drive as it it was your main drive - then you can fix any software issues with the broken drive.

--

I see on Amazon that they sell USBs with various OS versions pre-installed - that might be an option for you - however that opens you up to the possibility of malware - it's better to see if you can have a friend you trust prep the image for you - or even better if they can lend you their mac for an evening.

--

Its really hard to fix these issues without one of the three options above - so I (and I am guessing most people) don't bother - we just target mode the bad mac and fix it.

Note: Target mode is my preferred way of fixing, since I have a full OS to use when looking at the bad mac - so I can either copy files to the good mac or send them to another machine over the network.

Comment: Great info!! Thank you so much! Apple Care made it sound like I had no option. A friend helped me retrieve a backup via Terminal, but I would definitely like to try your options to fix the software without erasing on the macbook as some files were not transferred properly (somehow the transfer only retrieves temp versions of some documents).

I tried to downgrade to Mojave but it won't allow me to do so since Catalina is newer. Will look further into the options you listed. Thanks a bunch!

Option 3 you listed sounds like the most apt one. Have you got guide/resource for it you can share?

Comment: To be clear there are times when the best option is simply to wipe the drive and start again - however thats not an issue if you have confirmed you have got all the files copied off first.

Comment: gotcha. thank you!